# Botón en HTML, PHP y MySQL inserta valores en la base de datos aun cuando hay un error

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Tengo una lista de personas(pacientes) traidos desde una base de datos, cada persona tiene un valor en el campo 'primera_vez', en caso de que sea 1 se toma que si es su primera vez y se activa un botón su registro en la misma tabla de la aplicación web, en caso de que no, no muestra el botón.

El botón que solo aparece si primera_vez = 1 es el siguiente.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarPrimeraVez" onClick="obtenerIDPaciente(<?php echo $mostrar['idPaciente'];?>)">Cambiar Estatus</button>
```

El botón activa la modal siguiente:

```
<form id="frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente" action="POST" onSubmit="return editarPrimeraVezPaciente()">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditarPrimeraVez" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEditarPrimeraVez" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">El paciente ya no es primera vez</h5>
            <span type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" id="quitar_primeravez" name="quitar_primeravez" value="primera_vezSi" class="custom-control-input" required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="quitar_primeravez">Quitar estatus de primera vez</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <span class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</span> <!--se pone span por el onSubmit, si se da clic en cerrar tambien se guardaria el paciente-->
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick="">Guardar Datos</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

El botón de la Modal manda el idPaciente a la función de jQuery:

```
function obtenerIDPaciente(idPaciente){ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "idPaciente="+idPaciente,
        url: "../procesos/pacientes/editarPrimeraVez.php",
        success:function(respuesta){
            respuesta= jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
            console.log(respuesta);
        }
    });
}
```

Si el botón que abre la modal manda el ID a la función de arriba la modal se abre sin ningún problema, sin embargo sigue teniendo error que mostraré a continuación, y aún así genera el UPDATE  a la tabla.

Ahora, si yo el ID lo mando a la siguiente función de jQuery, al dar clic en el me despliega el mensaje de error de SweetAlert (swal.fire()), genera el UPDATE y luego me aparece la modal:

```
function editarPrimeraVezPaciente(idPaciente){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {form: $('#frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente').serialize(), idPaciente: idPaciente},
        url: "../procesos/pacientes/editarPrimeraVez.php",
        success: function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
            respuesta = respuesta.trim();
            if(respuesta == 1){
                $('#tablaPacientesLoad').load("pacientes/tablaPacientes.php");
                swal.fire("¡Listo!","Estatus cambiado con éxito", "success");
            }else{
                swal.fire(":(", "Error al actualizar estatus: " + respuesta, "error");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Ya en PHP la función que recibe los datos desde jQuery es la siguiente:

```
<?php
    include "../../clases/Usuarios.php";
        $Usuarios = new Usuarios();
        $idPaciente= $_POST['idPaciente'];
        echo $Usuarios -> editarPrimeraVez($idPaciente);
?>
```

Y el código de la clase que genera el UPDATE es el siguiente:

```
public function editarPrimeraVez($idPaciente){
            $conexion = Conexion::conectar();
            $sql = "UPDATE pacientes set primera_vez = 2 where id_paciente = '$idPaciente'";
            $respuesta= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
            return $respuesta;
        }
```

Y el mensaje del SweetAlert que me aparece es el siguiente:

[image: Este es el mensaje de Sweet Alert que me aparece.]

Ya intenté cambiar los nombres de las llaves en los $_POST y en el formulario pero me siguen saliendo errores diferentes, sin embargo el único que persiste es el de la imagen, ese es el factor común entre todos.

Lo que busco es poder hacer que el boton recoja un dato idPaciente de la base de datos y después abra una modal la cual contiene un input de tipo radio y si se presiona el radio y se da clic en el botón de la modal este último genere el UPDATE a otro valor que ya está en el query.

Como último comentario, cuando abro la modal y se hace el UPDATE en la base de datos, este si se hace en el ID correcto en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Que te está llegando al PHP? Pasa un var_dump($idPaciente); luego de $idPaciente= $_POST['idPaciente'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a proponer algunos cambios:

- Incluye el dato `idPaciente` en el formulario, puede ser con un campo oculto
- No asignes el evento submit en la etiqueta, es mejor hacerlo desde Javascript
- Corrige el HTML, sobra una etiqueta de cierre de botón
- Parece que tienes un problema con otros botones y por eso cambiaste la etiqueta a `<span>`; puedes seguir usando botones, solo especificando tipo `<button type="button">`, de lo contrario, por defecto serán `type="submit"`

```
<form id="frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente" method="POST">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditarPrimeraVez" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEditarPrimeraVez" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">El paciente ya no es primera vez</h5>
            <!-- Agregas el campo oculto -->
            <input type="hidden" name="idPaciente" id="idPaciente" value="">
            <span type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button><!-- Sobra este cierre -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio" id="quitar_primeravez" name="quitar_primeravez" value="primera_vezSi" class="custom-control-input" required>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="quitar_primeravez">Quitar estatus de primera vez</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <span class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</span> <!--se pone span por el onSubmit, si se da clic en cerrar tambien se guardaria el paciente-->
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick="">Guardar Datos</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Asigna el evento submit desde Javascript:

```
$('#frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente').on('submit', editarPrimeraVezPaciente);
```

Cuando abres la ventana modal, modificas el valor del campo `idPaciente`:

```
function obtenerIDPaciente(idPaciente) { 
    // Valor vacío hasta obtener respuesta
    $('#idPaciente').val('');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "idPaciente="+idPaciente,
        url: "../procesos/pacientes/editarPrimeraVez.php",
        success:function(respuesta){
            respuesta= jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
            console.log(respuesta);
            // Deberías validar si la respuesta fue correcta y poner el valor
            $('#idPaciente').val(idPaciente);
        }
    });
}
```

El método [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) convierte los datos del formulario en una cadena que puede ser enviada por URL: `var1=valor1&var2=valor2`; cuando tratas de enviar el formulario, creas un objeto que será difícil interpretar en PHP.

```
data: {
    form: $('#frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente').serialize(),
    idPaciente: idPaciente
},
```

En todo caso, ya teniendo el campo `idPaciente` dentro del formulario, debería ser solo:

```
data: $('#frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente').serialize(),
```

Sin embargo, también puedes usar el [objeto FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

```
// Esta función recibe el evento
function editarPrimeraVezPaciente(e) {
    // Cancelar evento para evitar error 404
    e.preventDefault();
    // Crear objeto FormData con todos los datos del formulario
    // el [0] es para obtener el elemento del DOM y no la instancia de jQuery
    let data = new FormData($('#frmEditarPrimeraVezPaciente')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        // El atributo correcto es method
        method: "POST",
        // Simplemente agregas el formulario
        data: data,
        url: "../procesos/pacientes/editarPrimeraVez.php",
        success: function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
            respuesta = respuesta.trim();
            if(respuesta == 1){
                $('#tablaPacientesLoad').load("pacientes/tablaPacientes.php");
                swal.fire("¡Listo!","Estatus cambiado con éxito", "success");
            }else{
                swal.fire(":(", "Error al actualizar estatus: " + respuesta, "error");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Finalmente, en PHP no estás validando correctamente el campo recibido, asegúrate de que exista, puede ser con una asignación ternaria para asignar un valor por defecto:

```
<?php
    include "../../clases/Usuarios.php";
    $Usuarios = new Usuarios();
    // Si no se recibió el valor, asignar cadena vacía
    $idPaciente= (isset($_POST['idPaciente'])) ? $_POST['idPaciente'] : '';
    // Verifica que hay un valor antes de ejecutar la consulta
    if($idPaciente != '') {
        echo $Usuarios -> editarPrimeraVez($idPaciente);
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ahora me manda un error diferente, me da un 404 y me manda a la url: http://localhost/Psic/vistas/POST?idPaciente=&quitar_primeravez=primera_vezSi,          solo que ahora también inserta el valor en la BD

Comment: @Jairo, ¿qué error recibes?

Comment: Me manda a una pagina con un 404 sobre la liga http://localhost/Psic/vistas/POST?idPaciente=&quitar_primeravez=primera_vezSi , esto despues de darle en el boton de Guardar en la Modal

Comment: @Jairo, edité la respuesta para quitar el `onsubmit="..."`, agregar el evento con Javascript y, en la función, cancelar el comportamiento normal.

Comment: Listo, con eso se solucionó el 404, sin embargo ahora sale un error al guarda la modal: **Error al actualizar estatus: string(0) "" 0**

Comment: @Jairo, antes de obtener id de paciente agrega `var_dump($_POST); die();` para ver lo que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Creo que no esta tomando el idPaciente, porque en la asignación del operador ternario asigna un valor vacío y es lo que esta imprimiendo en el SweetAlert, no se si lo indiqué en la pregunta inicial pero el idPaciente es solo un alias del SELECT que inicialmente hice es por eso que no asigné un input con ese value o name.

Comment: Logré manejar el mensaje de error y ya se visualiza correctamente, gracias por tu ayuda.